# How to change the postion of view in iphone app

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview

I have a view i want that when view is loaded it should change from the original position and displayed to new position but it is not working i am using following code.
I am calling this code in ViewDidLoad of the view.
it is landscape mode at initial at 512,374,1024,768 i want it to new position.

```
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                 animations:^{
                     self.view.frame = CGRectMake(512,100,1024,768);
                 }];
```

Comment: Add a subview on main view and change it's position to any where you want..

Comment: why are you not calling it in viewDidAppear?

Comment: thanks it workied in view didload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to move this code to `viewDidAppear:`. `viewDidLoad` is called when the view is loaded, but the view is not visible yet so you cannot see the animation.